Redirecting to same page with different parameters results in blank screen
I have a button that links to the same GAS page but with added parameters (say tag=a) in the URL. This works fine, but once I click another button that does the same thing (say tag=b), the page is blank:
First try: Button press -> Redirect to script.google.com/...?tag=a -> Success
Second Try: Button press -> Redirect to script.google.com/...?tag=b -> Blank page
This works no matter what the second tag is (it could be tag=b followed by tag=a, and tag=a returns a blank page)
HTML file:
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button" onclick="redirect('a')">A</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="redirect('b')">B</button>
</div>

function redirect(newTag) {
  var newUrl = '?tag='+newTag;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(v => {
    window.location = v,true;
  }).getUrl(newUrl)
}

Code.gs:
function doGet(e) {
  var page = e.parameter.page || 'recruit';
  var tag = e.parameter.tag || 'null';
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page);
  html.tag = tag;
  return html.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function getUrl(newUrl) {
  var currentUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return currentUrl + newUrl;
}

I've tried:

Different variations of window.location (such as window.location.href or window.location.replace)
Adding return false to redirect()
Setting a timeout with setTimeout()
Adding a random parameter (such as the date and time) in case of cache issues

and other minor restructuring to no avail. It's worth noting that window.open fixes this issue, but I would prefer avoiding opening new tabs every time this action is performed.
Also, this page will be embedded in an iframe, so I cannot use an alternative like window.top.location as this changes the parent window URL.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Did you have a chance to look at this question? How to stop redirected URL from being masked?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please add a [mcve]. The HTML file is not complete.

Thanks. I should have specified that my GAS will be embedded in an iframe, so I cannot use a solution like the one you linked. Edited my question to be more specific.

Based on my light reading here it seems that the behavior you are experiencing is what is an expected behavior for web apps created from HTML services of Google Apps Script.
